# Logging in with Super Admin credentials, loads client profile

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, expressionengine

I have copied a live site to a dev area, and I try to log in using the super admin credentials, however, EE CP says that I am only a client? I have used the same log in credentials on the live site and that works fine, just not sure why it would decide to do that randomly.

I have EE 2.6.1, and I have verified my login is in member group 1 (super admins) in PHPMyAdmin. I have also tried re-uploading the live database into a dev databse with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Could there be an IP address based restriction in your application/database ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, no there is no IP resriction. As I say, I can log into the live site as a super admin, but the same credentials only give me client access on the dev site :(